# What does a Diagonal Gaussian Distribution look like in 3 dimensions?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, data-visualization, reinforcement-learning

I was able to find https://brilliant.org/wiki/multivariate-normal-distribution/ and I am aware the the diagonal gaussian distribution is a special case where the only entries are on the diagonal, however I do not understand this entirely yet and finding a visualization or description of a visualization would help greatly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to visualize the "equidensity" level curves of the distribution as axis-aligned concentric ellipsoids in 3D, with most of the mass concentrated near the center (but this last point breaks down in higher dimensions)

Answer (score 1):

When you plot 2D diagonal gaussian samples to x-y plane, they'll form a circle or ellipse (not oblique). Obliqueness result from correlation. The link you provided has a visualization for 2D case, where the PDF can be plotted in 3 dimensions. If you consider the top view of this 3D PDF, you can get a sense how your 2D samples will look like on x-y plane when sampled. If you have a 3D diagonal Gaussian, then your samples will look like a sphere or ellipsoid (again not oriented). Your PDF is meaningful in 4D, i.e. because $t=f(x,y,z)$, and cannot be plotted directly.

Comment: thank you for this answer, it provided me with lots of useful information, I chose shimao's because it was simpler, but want to express my gratitude for this as well

Answer (score 0):

To give you more of a visual answer, this is a KDE plot using a mean = [0,0], cov = [[1,0], [0, 1]] looks like in seaborn:

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=[0, 0], cov=[[1,0],[0,1]], size=10_000), columns=["x", "y"])

plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.title("3D Diagonal Gaussian")
sns.kdeplot(data=df, x="x", y="y")
```

[image]